# Whitelist all sub domains with rebind-domain-ok

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq

Is it possible to whitelist a wildcard domain in dnsmasq with `rebind-domain-ok`?

I tried the following, but it did not work

```
rebind-domain-ok=/.example.com/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to restart dnsmasq service after updating the config file. The following configuration is working as intended.

```
rebind-domain-ok=/.example.com/
```

Comment: Please mark this answer then as the correct solution.